# How to specify specific elements based on their attributes using XPATH in LXML

Tags: python, html, lxml

I am trying to improve my understanding of XPATH.  I have a document that has many elements.  I am looking for font elements within the document that have some specific text that is bolded.

Here is an example of a font element inside a div element.  The font element has text that is bold that I want to capture

```
<div style="line-height:120%;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;font-size:10pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;">SECTION 1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Executive&nbsp;Summary</font></div>
```

Let me be clear this is part of a much larger document,. I found an XPATH tutorial and it described how to select specific elements

Just to make sure I am not running into an issue with how I am reading the file

```
tree=html.fromstring(open('c:\\mytest.htm')

x=tree.xpath('//font')
```

This worked as x has 3023 elements and when I examined them I found that they were all font elements.  Some were the elements I want.

I then tried to isolate the relevant elements by using

```
my_elements = tree.xpath('//font[@font-weight='bold']')
```

That did not work as my_elements is empty.  While writing this question I looked closer at the snip of html and played around some in IDLE.  I think the problem is that I there is not an attribute of the font tag font-weight. Font-weight is something related to the style attribute  The only attribute of the font tag in this example is style.  I want to say more but am afraid I will muddy the water too much

Bottom line I want to be able to use xpath to find all font elements that are bold and have the word section in the text I can do this by iterating through the elements and testing in a really clunky way

```
my_elements = [e for e in tree.iter() if e.tag == 'font' if 'bold' in e.values()[0] ]
my_elements = e for e in my_elements if 'section' in e.text_content().lower()
```

XPATH just looks like it is well worth understanding.

Thanks for any explanation.

Humm I finally am on the right track

```
testelem=tree.xpath('//font[contains(@style,"font-weight:bold")]')
```

okay now we use the and operator

```
testelem=tree.xpath('//font[contains(@style,"font-weight:bold") and contains(text(),"SECTION")]')
```

Now to make it case-insensitive

I am getting close to understanding how contains works but am happy for someone who does to put up a solution

```
testelem=tree.xpath('//font[contains(@style,"font-weight:bold") and starts-with(translate(text(),"SECTION","section"),"section")]')
```

Comment: Shouldn't you escape your quotation marks around *bold*?
 `my_elements = tree.xpath('//font[@font-weight='bold']')`,

Comment: Not from what I can see in the interpreter and from the examples I have seen in other places.

Comment: I think you have the answer. How about post it below so we can upvote it?

Comment: Well I don't fully understand it yet and am still trying to figure out how to check the text If I write the answer I want it to have a clear explanation so the next questioner understands what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

**Just realise this post is like > 2 years old**, anyway I still hope this answer will help someone who comes to this question.

You can use [regular expression](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#regular-expressions-in-xpath) in xpath from **lxml**. By default, XPath supports regular expressions in the [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org) namespace:

```
testelem = tree.xpath('//font[re:match(text(), \
                      "^(?i)section.*") and \
                      contains(@style, "font-weight:bold")]',
                      namespaces={'re': "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})

print testelem
[<Element font at 0x1042f49f0>]

for t in testelem:
    print t.text, t.attrib

SECTION 1.    Executive Summary {'style': 'font-family:inherit;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;'}
```